# Integrating video.js with vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, video.js

I am supposed to render a youtube video in a video.js player integrated with vue.js. I don't anything about integrations or really what is meant by it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [This package](https://surmon-china.github.io/vue-video-player/) maybe useful.

Comment: Please let me know which plugin you have used

Answer (score 1):

As solarhell mentioned, vue-video-player is what I have used. It works almost perfectly. The only caveat is that you have to use a ranged file result if streaming a video in chrome from a MVC app. Reference the Lib.Web.Mvc package from npm.

You will typically install it via NPM(if using NPM). npm install vue-video-player --save

Then you can use it inside of your vue component like this:

`<video-player class="video-player-box vjs-big-play-centered" :options="playerOptions"></video-player>`

The options prop is an object of video.js options that the component supports. This encompasses things such as if the video is muted, language, the video's url (youtube link), mime type, etc...

https://surmon-china.github.io/vue-video-player/